# How my apk can communicate with my local server?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, capacitor, localserver

I would like test my app on my phone, so i generate my apk but actually my app can't acces to my local server... i change my apiUrl with the ip on my computer but nothing has worked

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1) Forward your port (80) in your router settings. Then anyone outside your network can access your site using your WAN IP address (https://www.whatsmyip.org/). Note that then you won't be able to access it on localhost:8080 but using the LAN IP (192.168.x.x).

2) Use something like [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel your ports.

3) Use cloud hosting. Eg. free Heroku plan

Comment: For the first option how can i do that ? 
I need to forward the port 80 to do that even if my phone and my computer is connected on the same router ?
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @AlexandreAlcidas yes, this app only runs on your machine right now. I am not really into networks, but for sure you have to find something like firewall settings or 'advaced settings' and forward ports from your machine's private IP. Sample tutorial [here](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/)